# Cannot Access ViewModel Class member inside razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I cannot access a member of my class inside the view. All other members are accessible.

The following member "ListOfCategories" is not available in intellisense or at run time inside the view.

**Error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'ListOfCategories'**

My ViewModelClass

```
public class ArticleEditViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }       

        public List<Category> ListOfCategories = new List<Category>();
    }
```

My Razor View

```
@model rrrr.ViewModels.Article.ArticleEditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSecure.cshtml";
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Articles", "Index")
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model  => model.ID)
        <div class="tableHeader">
            <h2>Update Article</h2>
            </div>             
                <table id="RegistrationForm">                               
                    <tbody>                         
                        <tr>
                            <td>Title</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "registerinput" })                                    
                            </td>
                            <td class="leftWarning">
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
                            </td>
                        </tr>           

                        <tr>
                            <td>Category</td>
                            <td>
                                 @Html.DropDownList(model => model.ListOfCategories, Model.CategoryID)
                            </td>           
                            <td class="leftWarning">
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
                            </td>                 
                        </tr>                                                                                                                                      
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Update Article" class = "css_button_4"  />
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                    </tbody>                       
                </table>
}
```

Comment: Yes. All other members are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DropdownListFor` instead. The code will be something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.ListOfCategories.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.CategoryName, Value = c.CategoryId }))
```